# Handling two different response media types with openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm generating the sources of an OpenAPI contract with the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` maven plugin (version `5.4.0`).

I'm using the `java` generator and the `webclient` library.

I have one endpoint that is responding either `application/octet-stream` or `application/json` :

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "content": {
          "application/octet-stream": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "byte"
            }
          },
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TheResponseObject"
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

The problem is that the plugin is just considering the first media type (in the order of declaration) to generate the according java return type.

With the example above, I have to deal with `byte[]`.

If I invert the media types (`application/json` first), I have to deal with the `TheResponseObject`.

Is there a way to handle both of them and to get the good format according to the response headers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this, I've changed the contract to always handle `byte[]` in the response.

```
        "content": {
          "application/plain": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "byte"
            }
          },
```

Then, instead of calling `api.theEndpoint(...)`, I'm calling `api.theEndpointWithHttpInfo(...)` which sends back a `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` object.

According to the content type, I can choose how to process the result :

```
        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(reponse.getHeaders().getContentType())) {
            // parse json response (reponse.getBody()) 
        } else {
            // it's a pdf 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is: what result do you expect from `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`?

It's main idea is to generate API with methods like:

```java
ResponseEntity<TheResponseObject> get(...)
```

now, your schema defines that endpoint may return both `application/json` and `byte[]`, so, from java perspective API would look like:

```java
ResponseEntity<TheResponseObject> get(...);

ResponseEntity<byte[]> get(...);
```

which is not possible, because both methods has the same signature. In general it is possible to override `mustache` template ([spring template for example](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/api.mustache)) by placing your own version in `resources` directory and specifying `templateDirectory` in plugin configuration, but the best what you can get would look like:

```java
ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> get(...);
```

do you really need that?

Comment: In fact, the response type depends on the request body : sometimes we ask for json, sometimes we ask for pdf. So I've changed the contract to always handle `byte[]` and, according to the content type header, I process the body differently. Thank you for your help.

Comment: is it just a different representation of the same data? in that case you actually need a converter POJO->PDF.